# Skinned Inno Setup - Rtf Text Scroll Bar Issue

Tags: inno-setup

i'm using skinned inno setup installer using this code

```
[Files]
; Importing ISSkin DLLs :
Source: ISSkin.dll; DestDir: {app}; Flags: dontcopy
Source: Styles\Word_Style2010.cjstyles; DestDir: {tmp}; Flags: dontcopy

[Code]
// Importing LoadSkin API from ISSkin.DLL
procedure LoadSkin(lpszPath: String; lpszIniFileName: String);
external 'LoadSkin@files:isskin.dll stdcall';

// Importing UnloadSkin API from ISSkin.DLL
procedure UnloadSkin();
external 'UnloadSkin@files:isskin.dll stdcall';

// Importing ShowWindow Windows API from User32.DLL
function ShowWindow(hWnd: Integer; uType: Integer): Integer;
external 'ShowWindow@user32.dll stdcall';

function InitializeSetup(): Boolean;
begin
    ExtractTemporaryFile('VZ_Green.cjstyles');
    LoadSkin(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\VZ_Green.cjstyles'), '');
    Result := True;
end;
```

my problem is that the scroll bar isn't working !! though it was working when there was no skin.. is it possible to fix the issue ? i can't click on it and even sometimes it disappears ! sometimes it takes theme from my setup's background but still doesn't work like if it doesn't exist!! i already made researches about it but didn't found a solution yet, maybe it's a bug in cj styles? if yes, can you please guide me to draw a working scroll bar for my cj_style ? i can modify my cj style btw using some tools..
i tried many different styles, maybe not even something possible ?

[this is a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OA9No.png)

UPDATE : I've found the solution for the issue.. just use a modified version of inno setup and you'r all done :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is pretty simple!

I think it's not a bug in Isskin.dll !
just using a modified/improved version of inno does the work.

However, i don't know if attaching links here is legal or not as i'm too lazy to read rules (sorry about that) but here we go here is the path to the solution :
https://fileforums.com/showthread.php?t=103408

if link of simplified setup is not working anymore (it's a big famous forum never gonna die i think) but if it dies, the solution is by using any other modified version of inno setup in other forums.

you can browse the mentioned forum & you will find many source codes to edit them
Don't know how exactly they fixed the issue but this trick worked for me like charm!

[This is a screenshot for the working scrollbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YIaqb.png)

Comment: External links are fine but it is encouraged to at least summarize the key information in your own answer so that it remains useful to people in the future. External links typically die out over time.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in isskin.dll.

Recently I talked to a guy with this exact issue and also my version is bugged (however it is pretty old, maybe it was improved meanwhile).

If you have sources you can fix that by yourself otherwise contact the author of this skin mechanism to fix it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but i already fixed it now :)